# Nexcess Turpentine: Applying VCL on Configuration Save

Tags: varnish, turpentine, system-configuration

The Nexcess Turpentine extension for Magento offers a number of features for implementing a varnish configuration on your Magento system.  One of those features is the ability to, automatically, apply a new VCL configuration file to a running varnish instance when the `System -> Configuration` values change.

Question: When the `Nexcess_Turpentine` extension does this -- does it save the generated VCL out to disk anywhere?

I know you can save the varnish configuration on the Cache Management page -- I'm specifically interested if the automatic config application also saves out the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VCL is saved to the path given by the `turpentine_varnish/servers/config_file` configuration option, which defaults to `{{root_dir}}/var/default.vcl`.

See [`Nexcessnet_Turpentine_Model_Varnish_Configurator_Abstract::save()`](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/blob/master/app/code/community/Nexcessnet/Turpentine/Model/Varnish/Configurator/Abstract.php#L77-L99), which is called by [`Nexcessnet_Turpentine_Varnish_ManagementController::saveConfigAction()`](https://github.com/nexcess/magento-turpentine/blob/master/app/code/community/Nexcessnet/Turpentine/controllers/Varnish/ManagementController.php#L160-L161).

Answer (score 2):

My turpentine generates it to

```
/var/www/WEBROOT/public_html/var/default.vcl
```

To which I:

```
ln -s /var/www/WEBROOT/public_html/var/default.vcl /etc/varnish/default.vcl
```

You can change save file location under

`System -> Configuration -> Varnish Options -> Servers -> Config File Location` under `Default Scope`

Auto Apply will write the config file and send the config over the VCL admin and `reload` the server (a `restart` of course dumps the contents of Varnish, where as a `reload` just reloads the config (from either sent or file depends on arguments) whilst preserving cache contents)